# Publish Docker images using Spring Boot Plugin without credentials

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I've got a Gradle project with Spring Boot plugin and am trying to publish the image built by the plugin: `gradle bootBuildImage --publishImage`

The problem is to publish "either token or username/password must be provided" and we can't do that since we have different authentication mechanism in different environments. For example on local machine we're using `ecr-credentials-helper` and the pipeline uses `aws ecr get-login-token | docker login`.

Is there any way to force the plugin to let the docker handles the authentication? (I'm assuming the plugin uses the docker daemon on the host).

Currently I wrote a task to generate a token file using `aws ecr get-login-token` and read the token file in `bootBuildImage` task. But I don't like this solution, due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that replicates [`aws ecr get-login-password`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html) within Gradle, using the AWS Java SDK. Although you could instead invoke the CLI directly from Gradle, this makes the build script more fragile, as it then depends on having a certain version of the CLI installed. Particularly so since ecr login was a [breaking change](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-ecr-get-login) between v1 and v2 of the CLI.

This assumes you have your AWS credentials set up in some standard way that the [default credentials provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-chain) in the SDK will locate.

```groovy
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ecr.EcrClient

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.17.19")
        classpath "software.amazon.awssdk:ecr"
        classpath "software.amazon.awssdk:sts" // sts is required to use roleArn in aws profiles
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.springframework.boot"
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.3")
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
    // Rest of app dependencies
}

bootBuildImage {
    doFirst {
        String base64Token = EcrClient.create().getAuthorizationToken().authorizationData()[0].authorizationToken()
        String[] auth = new String( base64Token.decodeBase64() ).split(":", 2)

        docker {
            publishRegistry {
                username = auth[0]
                password = auth[1]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Adrian doesn't work anymore with newer Gradle versions.
I adapted his solution:

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootBuildImage
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ecr.EcrClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ecr.model.AuthorizationData
import java.util.Base64

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.20.121"))
        classpath("software.amazon.awssdk:ecr")
        classpath("software.amazon.awssdk:sts") // sts is required to use roleArn in aws profiles
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
}

tasks.withType<BootBuildImage> {

    val authData: Provider<AuthorizationData> = providers.provider {
        val ecrClient = EcrClient.builder().build()
        val authorizationData = ecrClient
                .getAuthorizationToken()
                .authorizationData()[0]
        return@provider authorizationData
    }

    val decodedEcrToken: Provider<String> = authData.map { String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(it.authorizationToken())) }
    val registryUsername: Provider<String> = decodedEcrToken.map { it.split(":")[0] }
    val registryPassword: Provider<String> = decodedEcrToken.map { it.split(":")[1] }

    docker {
        publishRegistry {
            username.set(registryUsername)
            password.set(registryPassword)
        }
    }
}
```